# How to transition a dragged UIView smoothly from one superview to another while maintaining the interaction in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIView that is being dragged after a UILongPressGestureRecognizer has succesfully executed. I am using gesture.location(in: superview) from the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to drive the position.

At some point during the dragging I want to remove the dragged view from its superview and place it into another, while maintaining the position and interaction seamlessly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into `UIDragInteraction`. Also see all of the [Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop) documentation including [Making a view into a drag source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/making_a_view_into_a_drag_source).